# Creating a SQL query to combine multiple related rows together

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I wonder if you can help me please? I'm new to SQL and I'm really struggling with this query. I've looked around but being new, I've gotten confused pretty quickly!

I have inherited a table of different addresses for a group of corporate customers. The table is on an Oracle 12c server and I'm using SQL Developer.

I'd like to append this information on to the end of another query so its a bit easier for people to see all of the relevant information for a single customer in the end report.

The table is laid out like so:

```
| CUST_ID | ADDRESS_TYPE | CONTACT_NAME | ADDRESS |  CITY  | ... |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1000|         SITE |      A SMITH |  A ROAD | A TOWN |
|     1000|      BUILDER |      B JONES |  B ROAD | B TOWN |
|     1000|    ARCHITECT |      A BROWN |  C ROAD | A CITY |
|     1001|         SITE |      B SMITH |  A LANE | C TOWN |
|     1001|    ARCHITECT |      D BROWN |  D ROAD | B CITY |
|     1002|         SITE |      E SMITH |  B LANE | D TOWN |
|     1002|    ARCHITECT |      C JONES |  B ROAD | A CITY |
|     1002|      BUILDER |      F SMITH |  C LANE | B TOWN |
```

What I would like to create is:

```
| CUST_ID | SITE_NAME | SITE_ADDRESS | SITE_TOWN | BUILDER_NAME | BUILDER_ADDRESS | BUILDER_TOWN | ... |
|    1000 |   A SMITH |       A ROAD |    A TOWN |      B JONES |          B ROAD |       B TOWN | ... |
|    1001 |   B SMITH |       A LANE |    A TOWN |         NULL |            NULL |         NULL | ... |
|    1002 |   E SMITH |       B LANE |    D TOWN |      F SMITH |          C LANE |       B TOWN | ... |
```

There are 3 `ADDRESS_TYPE` that I am interested in: `SITE`, `BUILDER` and `ARCHITECT`. So rather than have one row per `ADDRESS_TYPE` per `CUST_ID`, I would like to get one row per `CUST_ID` with the addressing information for each `ADDRESS_TYPE` as extra columns. I'd be using the `CUST_ID` to join the result to another query.

I dont know if I should be trying something with multiple joins or whether I can do some sort of sub-query?

Many thanks for your time and help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use joins

```
SELECT 
  BASE.CUST_ID,
  SITE.CONTACT_NAME AS SITE_NAME,
  SITE.ADDRESS AS SITE_ADDRESS,
  SITE.CITY AS SITE_CITY,
  BUILDER.CONTACT_NAME AS BUILDER_NAME,
  BUILDER.ADDRESS AS BUILDER_ADDRESS,
  BUILDER.CITY AS BUILDER_CITY,
  ARCHITECT.CONTACT_NAME AS ARCHITECT_NAME,
  ARCHITECT.ADDRESS AS ARCHITECT_ADDRESS,
  ARCHITECT.CITY AS ARCHITECT_CITY
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CUST_ID FROM TABLE_YOU_DID_NOT_NAME) BASE
LEFT JOIN TABLE_YOU_DID_NOT_NAME SITE ON BASE.CUST_ID = SITE.CUST_ID AND SITE.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'SITE'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_YOU_DID_NOT_NAME BUILDER ON BASE.CUST_ID = BUILDER.CUST_ID AND BUILDER.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'BUILDER'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_YOU_DID_NOT_NAME ARCHITECT ON BASE.CUST_ID = ARCHITECT.CUST_ID AND ARCHITECT.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'ARCHITECT'
```

Comment: Thanks Hogan, I wasnt sure if joins were a suitable thing to use when referencing the same table over and over again. I thought it might be really inefficient but now I know to just give it a go! Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Nikkunaku -- depending on the size of the table and the indexes defined and such this can be faster than using aggregation

Comment: I finally got round to trying out both methods and your join version got 380k results in 1.74 seconds versus just under 10 seconds for the conditional aggregate method. Changed yours to the answer as its easier to see whats going on and much quicker. Thanks again for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select cust_id,
       max(case when address_type = 'Site' then Contact_Name end) as site_name,
       max(case when address_type = 'Site' then Town end) as site_town,
       max(case when address_type = 'Site' then Address end) as site_address,
       max(case when address_type = 'Builder' then Contact_Name end) as builder_name,
       max(case when address_type = 'Builder' then Town end) as builder_town,
       max(case when address_type = 'Builder' then Address end) as builder_address,
      . . .
from t
group by cust_id;
```

Comment: Oooh this is totally new to me, thanks! It worked and it worked really quickly! Thanks for your help Gordon, I'm going to add conditional aggregates to my list of things to learn more about :D

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use PIVOT ( Just to be exhaustive in the different solutions )

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c5467/1)

```
select * from addresses 
pivot ( 
  MAX(CONTACT_NAME) CONTACT_NAME, 
  MAX(ADDRESS) ADDRESS, 
  MAX(CITY) CITY 
  FOR ADDRESS_TYPE IN ('SITE','BUILDER','ARCHITECT'));
```

@OP : I'd be curious about the time. I suppose must be like the aggregation method